# Investigating pointwise convergence and uniform convegence

Tags: calculus

I have a sequence of functions $f_{n}: [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as
$$f_{n}(x) = nxe^{-nx}.$$

Do i need to investigate both pointwise and uniform convergence of this sequence.

[image: i draw first 5 functions here on this picture]

So using this drawn functions I came to an suspicion that
for $x\in [0,a)$ it converges towards $y=0$,
and for $x\in(a,\infty)$ converges towards $x=0$.

I am not correct so i need a second opinion, also I am not sure what I should use for $a$.

So i will get that the sequence pointwise converges towards function $f$ but that function isn't continuous, so it will mean that this sequence doesn't converge uniformly.

Any help with choosing $a$ would help, also if I made any mistakes, I would really appreciate if you could point it out. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The functions of your image *aren't* $n x e^{−x}$.

Comment: Please check that my edit is correct. I fixed the function to $nx e^{-nx}$ as these are the functions plotted.

Comment: Te has adelantado un segundo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: $f_n\to 0$ pointwise (do the easy limit). For the uniform convergence, find the maximum of each $f_n$.

Comment: isn't there one interval that pointvise convergence is against y=0, as functions are getting really clsoe to y=0

Comment: @user246608, the interval of pointwise convergence is the whole $[0,\infty)$.